# camel jpa waiting for namespace handlers

Tags: jpa, osgi, fuseesb, jbossfuse, aries

I'm trying to write a RouteTest class for my camel jpa example and it does not work as expected because of the following line :

Bundle RouteTest is waiting for namespace handlers [http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/jpa/v1.1.0]

Please find here blueprint.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint"
        xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.0.0"
        xmlns:jpa="http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/jpa/v1.1.0"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
                http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
                http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd
                http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/jpa/v1.1.0 http://aries.apache.org/schemas/jpa/jpa_110.xsd">

    <bean id="jpa" class="org.apache.camel.component.jpa.JpaComponent">
        <jpa:unit unitname="persistence-pu" property="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <camelContext trace="true" id="blueprintContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
    <route id="persist">
        <from uri="direct:persist"/>
        <to uri="jpa:Person"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>
</blueprint>
```

and here RouteTest class :

```
public class RouteTest extends CamelBlueprintTestSupport {

    @Override
    protected String getBlueprintDescriptor() {
        return "/OSGI-INF/blueprint/blueprint.xml";
    }

    @Test
    public void testRoute() throws Exception {
        getMockEndpoint("mock:result").expectedMinimumMessageCount(1);
        ProducerTemplate producerTemplate = new DefaultCamelContext().createProducerTemplate(); 
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setName("Bob");
        producerTemplate.sendBody("direct:persist", person);

        // assert expectations
        assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to provide Aries Blueprint, and especially you need to provide the aries JPA dependencies. How do you Test your Routes? I'd suggest using Pax-Exam or probably better to use Pax-Exam-Karaf and intall the aries jpa features.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just added the blueprint and RouteTest code that I'm using.

Comment: do you have aries blueprint in your classpath (maven pom)? Oh, btw. the CamelBlueprintTestSupport doesn't work good with JPA, it's good for simple Camel tests but screwed with JPA due to PojoSR, I'd really recomend using Pax-Exam or better Pax-Exam-Karaf.

Comment: I've added dependencies to aries and now I have a new issue :( 

[         Blueprint Extender: 1] BlueprintContainerImpl         INFO  Bundle RouteTest is waiting for dependencies [(&(&(!(org.apache.aries.jpa.proxy.factory=*))(osgi.unit.name=jpa-example-pu))(objectClass=javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory))]